# The article 'the' in "She gained (the) ascendancy in the debate."

Tags: definite-article

> She gained the ascendancy in the debate.

vs.

> She gained ascendancy in the debate.

What is more common in both the usages? Is there any difference?

Comment: "The ascendancy" refers to one particular ascendency, while "she gained ascendency" could mean different people had ascendency at different times.

Answer (score 0):

> - She gained the ascendancy in the debate.
> - She gained ascendancy in the debate.

Nowadays both your sentences are used but **to gain ascendancy** is more common than **to gain the ascendancy**.They have exactly the same meaning.